# Advertisements in Android

Tags: android

I have a publisher account registered in US and I am deploying my application from that account. I have an admob account registered in India. Can I give ads to my app with both being registered with different details. This is my first app I am going to deploy Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is possible to use different accounts for Google Play and Admob.

Comment: actually publisher account is registered on the name of a company in US and admob account is registered on another company name in India. Is it ok to publish ads in my app as I am publishing the app from US and Giving ads from Indian admob account.

Comment: Technically, it is possible. You should check AdMob's Terms of Service to verify if there are any legal issues w.r.t such usage. You may consult your legal consultant for such a verification. As long as the app publisher agrees to the use of ads in (and hence monetization of) their apps, I guess, it should be fine.

Comment: I am the publisher and I myself am having the Admob account. But the Publisher account was created in US and the Admob in India. So will Google allow me to display the ads from Indian Admob account in an application published from US publisher account.

Comment: Please read the answer and my comment above. If your question is technical (which is what this forum caters to), then the answer is YES. Why don't you try and see for yourself?

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I dont have knowledge in publishing android app. Presently my plan is to publish my app through India publisher account for free for publicity and after checking the number of downloads I am planning to relaunch the app with few modifications made and from US publisher account. Will Google team allow me to do it.

Comment: Your questions seem to be more w.r.t application verification for publishing. There is no manual approval process (as is done for iOS App Store) and you are free to publish your app as long as you adhere to Google's guidelines. Read [Publishing Checklist for Google Play](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/preparing.html) for more information.